# Cover $x$ percent of a sphere's volume and a circle's area

Tags: geometry

You want to cover $95$% of a circle's area with rectangles which are inside the circle. Let's say you need $n$ number of rectangles for this. Then you want to cover $95$% of a sphere's volume with 3D rectangles,boxes which are inside the sphere, this requires $m$ number of boxes.  $m$ is going to be higher than $n$, right?

My guess is that it's getting harder to "approximate" any shape with boxes as you increase the dimension. By harder I mean it requires more and more boxes.

But how does it grow? Let's say you want to compare covering $95$% of a circle's area with covering $95$% of a $100$ dimensional sphere's volume.
Radius doesn't even matter I think.

Comment: This is closely related to packing rectangles into circles (or packing boxes into spheres) with fixed radius, where you want to cover a fixed part of the area (resp. volume) with the fewest possible packed elements.  There are probably some extensive calculations known for packing squares in circles, etc. which might help dispose of your intuition.

Comment: I think you should first define more precisely what you mean by good approximation. E.g.: the cubes required to fill 95% of a sphere of radius $1$ are more than the squares required to cover 95% of a circle of radius $1$... But you are comparing an area (2D-volume) with a a 3D-volume. It is like comparing square meters with cubic meters. If you proceed like that you might end up with some incongruence. Note that n-Volume of the hypersphere will stop increasing for $n>5$.

Comment: @dfnu:  I had interpreted the problem, in its "basic" form, to ask for fewest rectangles "inside the circle" covering 95% of its area *without overlap*.  But on reading your Comment I agree the wording needs to be tightened on that point.  Here is a [previous StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28501289/487781) that treats a restricted form (using rectangles of specified *lengths*) of the problem.  I think the computational approaches outlined there are relevant.